# Memory allocation in cross platform C++ library

Tags: c#, android, c++, cross-platform

I am developing a cross-platform C++ library to be consumed by C# (Xamarin) client.

My understanding is that, for memory allocation and passing it back and forth, I have 2 options:

In my unmanaged C++ code, allocate using CoTaskMemAlloc and SysAllocString, Mark the Interop Marshaler appropriately using MarshalAs so that runtime can delete the memory using Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() or Marshal.FreeBSTR()

If the allocated memory is returned as IntPtr, then the managed code has to manually unmarshal the pointer and then free the memory using the appropriate Free method.

OR

In managed code, use the Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem method to allocate memory, pass the buffer to unmanaged C++ library, let it fill it and return, and finally in managed code, use Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem to free the memory.

This would work in Windows OS but since my C++ library has to be cross platform, what is the equivalent memory allocation/deallocation mechanism on Android or iOS ?

My understanding is that using malloc in C++ is not advisable since the implementation can vary.

Thanks